# Export node variable in windows like on mac

Tags: node.js, windows, macos, export, mocha.js

I would like to pass variables to a mocha test, which is not as simple as expected. Passing a variable like this:

```
npm run test --scope=28
```

is not possible, because mocha will catch the input. I also tried to use the npm minimist package and using a user prompt failed also.

Anyway my colleagues are using a mac and are able to pass an env variable by using this command

```
export testscope="18" && npm run test
```

But unfortunately this will not work in Windows. So my question is, is there a similar export command for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CMD.EXE](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) `set` command for this, acts like `export` on *NIX.

```
set testscope=18 && npm run test
```

You did not say which shell you are using, in [PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx), you might want to do this:

```
$env:testscope= 18; npm run test
```

The OP finally decided on installing the Linux subsystem of Windows, to do this, you issue the following in Powershell ("opened as Administrator"):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to use the PowerShell but set testscope=18 && npm run test did not worked. Because of the "&&". So I tried using the first command and then the second, which did not worked out. I'm installing the Linux bash (subsystem) now in Windows.

Comment: I ended up installing the linux bash as a subsystem on windows and used the command there, which are working great.

Comment: If somebody find this post and will need more information about Linux as a subsystem: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/